# LLVM: ERROR: Constant unimplemented for type

Tags: llvm

Why does the LLVM pure interpreter performs differently from the JIT-enabled interpreter with respect of array constants? (LLVM 3.8.1)

I have the following code:

```
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128    :128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.9.0"

%MyType = type { i8* }

define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) nounwind uwtable {
  %const.arr = alloca [8 x i8], align 8
  store [8 x i8] c"\D0\CFT\15\01\00\00\00", [8 x i8]* %const.arr
  %1 = bitcast [8 x i8]* %const.arr to %MyType*
  ret i32 0
}
```

If I compile this with `llvm-as test.llvm` and `lli test.llvm.bc`, I get no error.
On the other hand, If I hit `lli -force-interpreter test.llvm.bc` I get the following error:

```
LLVM ERROR: ERROR: Constant unimplemented for type: [8 x i8]
```

Inspecting the code, I don't see anything wrong with it. Why does it perform differently when I force the interpreter?

Comment: Mac os doesn't allow AOT (ahead of time) compilation. Hence, you cannot use the force interpreter option.